# how to set content of a speicific node inside tinymce?

Tags: editor, tinymce

I want to set content of an element to the first node of the tiny mce. I can retrieve the id of this node, but don't know how to set content inside it.

Help Appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using something like the following. Make sure to enter valid html.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().firstChild.innerHTML='<span class="customStyle">Testtext</span>';
```